# Serialize NodaTime LocalDate and LocalDateTime to JSON using OData

Tags: odata, json-deserialization, nodatime, localdate, odata-v4

I am using OData V4 with NodaTime.

Currently to serialise my LocalDate into a ISO date I have to do this in my API controller resource/edm

```
StartDate = x.StartDate == default(LocalDate) ? null : x.StartDate .ToIsoDateString()
```

But this means doing this for every date. I'd like to serialise this automatically. I have my own LocalDateConverter (using Newtonsofts JsonConverter implementation) that converts LocalDates in normal rest calls to the format yyyy-MM-dd, but these are not picked up in OData requests as I think the routes are registered differently.

Is there a way to serialise LocalDate and LocalDateTime for OData requests?

Comment: I don't know anything about OData, but are you aware that there's a NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet package? That could save you some effort. Additionally, it sounds like `StartDate` should be a `LocalDate?` rather than using `default(LocalDate)` as a sentinel value.

Comment: @JonSkeet the above was just my hardcoded way or parsing out the LocalDate to an iso string, and if its null, then just return null. I will look at those serialisers thanks, but its more hooking them into the pipeline for OData that I think is the issue

Comment: But a `LocalDate` is never null, because `LocalDate` is a value type. If you want to handle a null value, you need to use `LocalDate?`.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed it could be improved to use a nullable version